# HttpURLConnection Post issues

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have the following code in my program, used for inserting record -

```
private Void downloadUrl() throws IOException {
        String postParameters;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        postParameters = "name="+ URLEncoder.encode(user.name,"UTF-8")
                +"&age="+URLEncoder.encode(user.age+"","UTF-8")
                +"&username="+URLEncoder.encode(user.username,"UTF-8")
                +"&password="+URLEncoder.encode(user.password,"UTF-8");

        if (postParameters != null) {
            Log.i("Post", "POST parameters: " + postParameters);
            try {
                URL urlToRequest = new URL(SERVER_ADDRESS);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlToRequest.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(30000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(
                        postParameters.getBytes().length);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                out.print(postParameters.getBytes());
                out.close();

                // handle issues
                int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                Log.e("Response", "The response is: " + statusCode);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // handle invalid URL
                Log.e("Response", "invalid URL");
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                // hadle timeout
                Log.e("Response", "handle timeout");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // handle I/0
                Log.e("Response", "handle IO problem");
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The code is showing no errors and the logged entries are

> 09-27 12:24:17.944    5006-5039/? E/Response﹕ The response is: 200
>   09-27 12:24:33.729    5006-5118/? I/Post﹕ POST parameters: name=vibha&age=25&username=vib&password=1234

But when I check the database, the new record is not created.

But if I use PHP code in a file and post the same parameters,the records are getting inserted.

My requirement for help and guidance is how to pass the post parameter in the HttpURLConnection class

Comment: the problem is server-side, not client side

Comment: Your code *looks* okay-ish.

Comment: As others have mentioned before me, you are barking up the wrong tree, what you need to do is to add logging to your php code or debug it when the request from your app comes through. It will show you where the error is.

Comment: Thanks Blackbelt, Tobia, your assurance helped. The problem was on server side.